# Convert Multiple XML files into single CSV using XSLT and C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, csv

I'm trying to convert XML file to CSV using XSLT. It works. I was able to convert XML and get the output I want using XSLT.

The challenge I'm facing right now is that I have many many XML files in a single location. I want to get ALL the data from all XMLs and put them into a single CSV file.  I have a for loop that goes through the folder and gets the XML files and then exports it to CSV. However, every time it converts new XML it overrides the data in the current CSV file. So the end result is I only get one row in the CSV file instead of 500 (if there's 500 xml files).

Here's the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace XSL
{

class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //declaring xmlFile
            string xmlfile ;

            //Loading the XSLT template
            String xsltfile = "C:\\Win\\XMLReader\\XSL\\csv.xsl";

            //get folder location

            string d = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            //Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());

            //first part of the location path

            String firstPath = @"\\tripx-exportm\\output\\Skill 53115;1_";

            //full path
            string fullPath = firstPath + d.ToString() + "_000000" + @"\\IDX";

            //Get files from a folder

            string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.xml");

           //get each file in the folder
            foreach (string file in filePath)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                xmlfile = file;
                Transform(xmlfile, xsltfile);

            }

            //Get the count of XML files in the current folder
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
            int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;

            Console.WriteLine("Count of XML files: " + count);


            //Transform(xmlfile, xsltfile);
            Console.WriteLine("press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

    }

    public static void Transform(string xml, string xslt)
    {
        try
        {
            //load the xml doc

            XPathDocument myDoc = new XPathDocument(xml);

            XslCompiledTransform myXL = new XslCompiledTransform();


            //load the xslt doc
            myXL.Load(xslt);

            //create the output

            XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("result.csv", null);

            myXL.Transform(myDoc, null, myWriter);

            myWriter.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        };
    }

}
```

}

[XSLT file](http://xsltransform.net/gWcDMey)

Any suggestions on how I can put the data from multiple XMLs into a single CSV?

Thank you

Comment: Am I right in saying that this question is really "How to append to a file when using `XmlTextWriter`?"

Comment: To read multiple documents, look at the `document()` function. You'll have to come up with some mechanism (parameters, a control file, whatever) to tell the stylesheet which documents you want to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a different approach. It may not be the best possible solution, but it works for me.

In my code, I added a counter to count the number of XMLs that were processed. It increments.
In my Transform procedure instead of hard coding the name "result.csv", I generate the name:

```
string Result = "result" + count.ToString() + ".csv";
```

And I use that name in the XMLWriter

```
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(Result, null);
```

This way it generates a single CSV for every XML and it will not override the existing one.

Then I wrote another procedure that combines all the CVSs into one:

```
 private static void JoinCsvFiles(string[] csvFileNames, string outputDestinationPath)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        bool columnHeadersRead = false;

        foreach (string csvFileName in csvFileNames)
        {
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(csvFileName);

            string columnHeaders = tr.ReadLine();

            // Skip appending column headers if already appended
            if (!columnHeadersRead)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(columnHeaders);
                columnHeadersRead = true;
            }

            sb.AppendLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
        }

        File.WriteAllText(outputDestinationPath, sb.ToString());
    }
```

And in the main, I just call

```
string[] csvFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(".", "result*.csv");

        JoinCsvFiles(csvFileNames, "CsvOutput.csv");
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right constructor overload for the `XmTextWriter` to take a stream, rather than a file name.

The help on MSDN says this about the file name overload:

> The filename to write to. If the file exists, it truncates it and
>   overwrites it with the new content.

So you should to do this to `Transform` to make it work:

```
public static void Transform(Stream stream, string xml, string xslt)
{
    var myDoc = new XPathDocument(xml);
    var myXL = new XslCompiledTransform();
    myXL.Load(xslt);
    using(var myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.Default))
    {
        myXL.Transform(myDoc, null, myWriter);
        myWriter.Flush();
        myWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Then the calling code should look like this:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("result.csv", FileMode.Create))
{
    foreach (string file in filePath)
    {
        Transform(fs, file, xsltfile);
    }
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

I've taken out the (bad) exception handling, and comments, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. After adding this code, it generates the csv for the first XML, and it chokes. "Stream was not writable"

Comment: @user1426542 - Try taking out the `myWriter` using statement (just declar the instance) and the `myWriter` flush and close. If it works then the closing of the `myWriter` is causing the issue. Otherwise I would just check that you've put everything in the same way that I've done.